# Playstore shows beta label bedside production app

Tags: android, google-play

Few days ago, I promoted my beta `(open beta test)` application to production. Everything went well. I can search my app in playstore. But there is a one problem, playstore didn't remove `(beta)` label beside my app name. I want to remove that label. How can I do it or am I missing something.

Comment: Create new APK Upload it in beta, then move to Production from Beta testing. I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: Could it be the phased update system Google uses?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Comment: @Machavity, I disagree with your reasoning. Customer service questions are off-topic for the reasons spelled out in the answer to the question you link. This is not actually a customer service question. Yes, Google's CS could answer, but it doesn't require the special access available to a CS rep. This question is identical-in-spirit to any other question asking how to use a tool commonly used by programmers. The tool just happens to be a web page. If the solution required customer service, then it would be off-topic, but the answer implies all that's needed is in the UI available to the user.

Comment: @AZED are you able to remove BETA label

Comment: @AZEd I am facing the same problem, were you able to remove it?

Answer (score 7):

In order to remove the (beta) label of your app from play store. you must opt out of testing(close the beta testing)
so in order to make everything clean, please close the test, let all your testers opt-out of the test and move your app to production.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Adding a screenshot of the UI showing how this is done (with hand drawn red circles), or a screen movie showing it being done (i.e. a GIF of activity on your screen) would significantly improve this answer.

Comment: @Sagar,  how much time it may take remove beta label after disabling .?

Comment: @Sagar if I disable beta testing, do the testers have to re-download it from production? My production users are using the Beta version of the app. My worry is will the production users face any issue by just disabling beta testing?