# Remove beta label bedside production app

Tags: android, google-play-console

I promoted my application from beta (open beta test) to production. but in playstore didn't remove (beta) label beside my app name. I want to remove that label. How can I do it.?

I have seen below link and tried disabling beta testing , even though its not affecting, still am able to see (beta) tag beside my app

[Playstore shows beta label bedside production app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44364055/playstore-shows-beta-label-bedside-production-app)

Comment: It takes more than 24 hours to roll-out.

Comment: After 6 hours its updated, now am not seeing BETA tag in play store

Answer (score 3):

check if you have your email saved as a tester. because in my case it was beta for me only and normal production app for everyone else. Try to search for your app from an incognito browser or so to make sure it is as it is for the public.